# When entities started being plural?

Tags: parmenides

As per the creator of the idea, Parmenides, entities started as one (entity). When or who established entities as many?

Comment: To some extent this is language-based. For example in American English, a committee is one thing so "The committee has decided ..." In British English, a committee consists of several people so, "The committee have decided."

Comment: Parmenides was not the creator of that idea, entities (*ta onta*) appeared in pre-Socratic philosophy before him, e.g. in the famous [Anaximander's quote](https://ndpr.nd.edu/news/he-beginning-of-western-philosophy-interpretation-of-anaximander-and-parmenides/). It is rather Parmenides's singular Being (*to on*) that was derivative and rather idiosyncratic.

Comment: There were the *monism* of the [Milesians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pre-Socratic_philosophy#Milesian_school) and then [Xenophanes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xenophanes#Metaphysics) and [Heraclitus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heraclitus) that rejected the notion of unity proposed by the Milesians. Then the [Eleatic school](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pre-Socratic_philosophy#Eleatic_school) with Parmenides, and later the [Atomists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pre-Socratic_philosophy#Atomist_school).

Answer (score 1):

That things are many is the natural view. You look around and see a variety of things. Oak trees, light reflecting off the ocean onto low scudding clouds, young pale green blades of grass in a sultry field, human beings and so on. Parmenides considers beings as a whole, he tries to think of everything. This is an act of reflection, not of experience of daily dealings. The question becomes powerful when different groups of thoughtful people try to speak to each other on the notion that each one wants to understand what the other is saying, and in the same way they mean it. Then questions such as what is meant by saying something is not come in, as in Plato's Sophist. One can ask, is not being a kind of being? The word being starts to take on a specific content. Of course, one can see that also, in Parmenides' own writing and in the Platonic dialogue of that name where Zeno, his student, shows the inverse, he shows that many can not be. One can say, perhaps, that the saying about being is only for the eyes of the soul or for the intellect. It refers to the world, but in a way that is unavailable to beings without reason.